# Does JSF store my helper class, which is referenced in my ManageBean in the session too?

Tags: session, jsf, jsf-2, transient, session-scope

Just a doubt regarding how JSF session management works

I got a managedbean as :

```
@ManagedBean(name="loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable
{

        private String userName;
        //getter and setter

        private String password;
        //getter and setter

        // Getting through spring injection
        @ManagedProperty(value="#{userBO}")
        private UserBO userBO;
        //setter method

        public fetchUserDetails(){
        User  user = userBO.getUSer(this.userName);
        //some processing
        }
    // more methods
    .
    .
    .
}
```

So now since the bean is sessionScoped, will JSF keep my "userBO" object in the session too? 
I believe that variables with both the setters and getters are likely to be stored in the session. Correct me if I am wrong.
Or do I have to declare "userBO" as transient so that it is ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your session is persisted in memory between requests, any other objects it references will be kept and not be eligible for garbage collection. There is no task that walks an object's internals setting references to `null`. Managed properties are only evaluated when the bean is created and before it is placed into scope.

Setting `userBO` to `transient` would only have an effect if the session was serialized (via passivation to disk, via session replication, etc.)

Comment: Session persistence is server dependent, and I wounldn't want to control that. So you mean to say my userBO is sessionScoped too? That's bad :/

Comment: Session objects are no different from any other object in the VM in this regard. Hard references mean objects cannot be garbage collected. Perhaps you can set `userBO` to null after you are done with it (see also `@PostConstruct`.) Or perhaps you need to revisit your bean design if you are leaking objects out of scope - you could use a request-scope object to populate your session-scope object using `userBO` for example.

Comment: Thanks, I guessed the same. Apparently best option I see here is to make my ManagedBeans as requestScoped and manually set my session Objects :/

Comment: Inject your session objects into the relevant request objects.

Comment: That is exactly what I had done previously (injecting this session object) but then I realized that my userBO is also getting linked to my session object. So now I got to move my session objects into a separate class(sessionBean) and mark that as sessionScope, and inject that where ever required.
Thanks again for the info :)